# Test the hypothesis ....

Tags: standard-deviation, means

A random sample of size 20 from a normal population give a sample mean of 42 and sample
standard deviation of 6. Test the hypothesis that the population mean is 44 at 5 % level of
significance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First calculate the statistic

$$t=\frac{44-42}{6}\sqrt{20}=1.49$$

then decide, using the fact that $t\sim \mathcal{T}_{(19)}$